# Changing from APA citation style with overleaf

Tags: citing, apa-style, apacite

I am currently working the references citation style which is based on APA style, but with slight differences.
For example, the following is with the standard APA style:

> Anton, R. J. (1990). Drawing the line: An exploratory test of ethical behavior in negotiations. *International Journal of Conflict Management, 1(3)*, 265-280.

But the required citation style is shown as followed:

> Anton, R. J. (1990). Drawing the Line: An Exploratory Test of Ethical Behavior in Negotiations. The International Journal of Conflict Management 1(3), 265-280.

In other words, the name of the journal is not italic, and there is no comma between its name and its volume. Are there any ways to adapt from the APA citation style, or even customize a new one to do so?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB) or your current code to work on.